# How to apply vlookup on the different workbook range?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to apply VLOOKUP to get the data from a workbook named `LPD`with sheet `RAS(Offshore)` having my lookup range. I want to look for the column `A` which is present in a different workbook named `fresher` with sheet as `DestSh`.So I want the results after applying VLOOKUP in the sheet `DestSh` in column `z`.

I have tried

```
iSCount = 2
For Each cell In DestSh.Range("Z2:Z" & lstRowofIpSheet)   
    With DestSh
        sFormula = "=VLOOKUP(DestSh!$A" & iSCount & ",'" & sLPDFileName & "]RAS(Offshore)'!$B:$F,5,false)"    
        .Range("Z" & iSCount).Formula = sFormula
        iSCount = iSCount + 1
    End With
Next cell
```

But I am getting the error as: `Application defined or Object defined error`.

Any help or suggestions shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing the opening `[`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
sFormula = "=VLOOKUP(DestSh!$A" & iSCount & _
            ",'" & sLPDFileName & "]RAS(Offshore)'!$B:$F,5,false)"
```

Missing an opening square bracket:

```
sFormula = "=VLOOKUP(DestSh!$A" & iSCount & _
            ",'[" & sLPDFileName & "]RAS(Offshore)'!$B:$F,5,false)"
```